# Reciever SKViaPoint for class message is a forward declaration

Tags: ios, objective-c, skmaps

I was trying to make an instance of SKViaPoint with

```
SKViaPoint *point = [SKViaPoint viaPoint:1 withCoordinate:coordinate];
```

But I am getting a following error:
[image]

So "No known class method for selector".

I checked and I do have the latest version of Skobbler SDK, but I also checked and there is no actual ViaPoint.h.
Not in mine neither in the Demo project.

So Im wondering is there anything else I should import in order to be able to make SKViaPoint instance?

Comment: the "SKViaPoint.h" file is located in SKMaps_iOS_2.5.0_withDemo ▸ SKMapsFrameworkDemo ▸ SKMaps.framework ▸ Versions ▸ A ▸ Headers▸

Answer (score 2):

Ok, what solved it was importing the actual class, from SKMaps framework.
Importing framework only didn't do the trick

```
#import <SKMaps/SKViaPoint.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, in the 2.5 Swift build, SKMaps.h in SKMaps.framework/Headers is missing some imports: SKViaPoint, SKViaPointState and SKSearch. 
You can add them manually or use the header found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/etup3a7eeahukho/SKMaps.h?dl=0).

In the next update we'll fix this issue.