# How to create an array of SKViaPoint in swift - Skobbler API

Tags: swift, skmaps, skviapoint

I want to calculate a route with several viaPoints.

```
    let route = SKRouteSettings()
    route.startCoordinate = self.userLocation
    route.destinationCoordinate = endCheckpoint.location.coordinate
    route.viaPoints = viaPointsArray
    SKRoutingService.sharedInstance().calculateRoute(route)
```

But I cannot declare SKViaPoint. Class declaration seems to be missing as I'm getting "Use of unresolved identifier 'SKViaPoint' when I try to declare a variable"

Is there something i'm missing?
I remember when I was working in Objective C, that I needed to import SKViaPoint.h specifically [this is the old question about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31910149/reciever-skviapoint-for-class-message-is-a-forward-declaration/32111710#32111710)

So what should I do in swift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Swift implementation is missing some imports (SKViaPoint being one of them).

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31910149/reciever-skviapoint-for-class-message-is-a-forward-declaration) questions for a fix